# how to categorize Bubble Map using colors

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

i am trying create bubble map to using plotly.graph_objects(go.Scattergeo), categorize using colors(yellow,blue,green,red) with column value 0 to 50,50 to 70,71 to 80,81 to 100

colors = ["yellow","green","blue","red"]
limits = [(0,50),(51,70),(71,80),(81,100)]

```
for i in range(len(limits)):
lim = limits[i]
df_sub = df[lim[0]:lim[1]]
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    lon = df['Longitude'],
    lat = df['Latitude'],
    text = df['text']  ,
    mode = 'markers',
    #marker_color = df['value'],
    marker = dict(
        #size = limits[i]*20000,
        size = 10,
        color = colors[i],
        line_color='rgb(40,40,40)',
        line_width=0.5,
        sizemode = 'area'
    ),
    [name = '{0} - {1}'.format(lim\[0\],lim\[1\])
    ))][1]
```

Comment: Please refer to the [official reference for examples](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-maps/#united-states-bubble-map).

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided any sample data.  I've included COVID data for Scotland
- really you are describing [pandas cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) functionality
- have demonstrated this with ranges and colours you defined

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"areaCode": ["S12000034", "S12000006", "S12000047", "S12000017", "S12000018", "S12000020", "S12000013", "S12000023", "S12000026", "S12000027", "S12000030", "S12000041", "S12000035", "S12000014", "S12000039", "S12000033", "S12000045", "S12000021", "S12000029", "S12000040", "S12000036", "S12000005", "S12000042", "S12000008", "S12000010", "S12000011", "S12000049", "S12000019", "S12000050", "S12000048", "S12000038", "S12000028"], 
 "areaName": ["Aberdeenshire", "Dumfries and Galloway", "Fife", "Highland", "Inverclyde", "Moray", "Na h-Eileanan Siar", "Orkney Islands", "Scottish Borders", "Shetland Islands", "Stirling", "Angus", "Argyll and Bute", "Falkirk", "West Dunbartonshire", "Aberdeen City", "East Dunbartonshire", "North Ayrshire", "South Lanarkshire", "West Lothian", "City of Edinburgh", "Clackmannanshire", "Dundee City", "East Ayrshire", "East Lothian", "East Renfrewshire", "Glasgow City", "Midlothian", "North Lanarkshire", "Perth and Kinross", "Renfrewshire", "South Ayrshire"], 
 "long": [-2.79208, -4.02863, -2.98251, -4.66103, -4.75387, -3.20202, -6.65722, -2.90025, -2.85869, -1.37344, -4.32595, -2.8921, -5.22114, -3.83619, -4.52074, -2.20398, -4.22417, -4.7246, -3.83272, -3.60909, -3.27826, -3.75316, -2.97095, -4.29057, -2.72435, -4.3606, -4.21479, -3.11738, -3.9514, -3.88484, -4.56834, -4.72899], 
 "lat": [57.234692, 55.09621, 56.231121, 57.586571, 55.900299, 57.476799, 58.199379, 58.94334, 55.525951, 60.504951, 56.249531, 56.725182, 56.28944, 56.000751, 56.0014, 57.166969, 55.95829, 55.72789, 55.60453, 55.8992, 55.911201, 56.147839, 56.4776, 55.496738, 55.94207, 55.74868, 55.876492, 55.82111, 55.868141, 56.575279, 55.848621, 55.23008], 
 "newCasesByPublishDate": [8, 6, 20, 5, 4, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 5, 10, 7, 12, 5, 22, 15, 16, 39, 24, 140, 10, 41, 24, 28, 16, 117, 22, 54, 32, 44, 38], 
 "pop_total": [261210.0, 148860.0, 373550.0, 235830.0, 77800.0, 95820.0, 26720.0, 22270.0, 115510.0, 22920.0, 94210.0, 116200.0, 85870.0, 160890.0, 88930.0, 228670.0, 108640.0, 134740.0, 320530.0, 183100.0, 524930.0, 51540.0, 149320.0, 122010.0, 107090.0, 95530.0, 633120.0, 92460.0, 341370.0, 151950.0, 179100.0, 112610.0]})


fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scattergeo(
        lat=df["lat"],
        lon=df["long"],
        text=df["areaName"],
        marker={
            "color": pd.cut(
                df["newCasesByPublishDate"],
                bins=[0, 50, 70, 80, 100],
                labels=["yellow", "green", "blue", "red"],
            )
        },
    )
)
fig.update_layout(geo={"fitbounds": "locations"})
```